# Where was Grebenrodt in Hesse, Germany, in the late 1500s?

Tags: germany, historical-gazetteer, renaming-places

In *Sippenbuch der Stadt Sontra in Hessen (etwa 1700 - 1825) 4. Teil*, Wilm Sippel gives the following entry on page 205:

> (13893)
> SIPPEL,Marx in 6445 Heinebach, siehe Urkunden in Sippel 5, S.219-220 und 8, S.2!
> zahlt 1 Gulden, weil er über die Grenzsteine geackert hat, 1582 hat ihn
> der Cunz Landefeld beschimpft.

> Zahlt seit 1575 Rauchheller für das Haus, das vorher Gertrud Ellenberger hat-
> te, zinst seit 1576 4 Albus für eine Wiese, die vorher der Kehr zu Ubach
> (3509 Eubach?) hatte und vor diesem Junghenn Lachmund; zinst seit 1582 3
> Albus für eine Wiese im Grebenrodt, die vorher Heinz Schweitzer hatte.

Roughly translated:

> (13893)
> SIPPEL, Marx in 6445 Heinebach, see documents in Sippel 5, p.219-220 and 8, p.2! pays 1 guilder because he plowed over the boundary stones, in 1582 Cunz Landefeld reprimanded him.

> Paid Rauchheller since 1575 for the house that Gertrud Ellenberger previously had, since 1576 has been paying 4 Albus taxes for a meadow that previously had the Kehr zu Ubach (3509 Eubach?) and before this Junghenn Lachmund; has paid taxes since 1582 3 Albus for a meadow in Grebenrodt, which Heinz Schweitzer previously had.

I'm specifically interested in the mention of Heinz Schweitzer.  However, where was Grebenrodt?  I know that Wilm Sippel was using the local tax records as a source for this information.  He doesn't specify which town's tax records he used for a given citation, though I would assume that all of the tax information in this entry was from Heinebach.

My question is, however, where (or what) was Grebenrodt?  I've not found other reference to that name elsewhere, and this is the only reference to that name in the five volumes of Sippel's work.  lagis-hessen has an entry for a "Grebenrod-Höhe", but it's a district in Heidenrod, which is nowhere near Hesse.  Volkssprache und Volkssitte im Herzogthum Nassau, Volume 3 has an entry that mentions that "Grebenrodt" was one of the earlier names of Egenroth used in the 1600s (along with "Grebenrode", "Grebenrod", "Grebenroth", "Greberodt", and "Grebert"), but Egenroth is only 5 km away from Heidenrod, and they both are about 220 km away from Heinebach. The only use I can find of that name in a Hessen context is a "Wilhelm von Grebenrodt", who lived around 1390.

Comment: beschimpft - reprimanded, instead of insulted. zinst - paid taxes, rather than interest

Comment: [Grebenroth](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Grebenroth,+65321+Heidenrod,+Germany/@50.1988392,7.9295034,991m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x47bddb20180eb77d:0xed5aea7a5d89b306!8m2!3d50.1984921!4d7.9338485!16s%2Fg%2F122jq9m0?entry=ttu) seems to still exist, separately from Egenroth, about 1.62 km to the NW.

Comment: I'm not sure, but either way, that one is very unlikely to be the one referenced in this entry.